# user creation dumping using trigger and fucntions

Tags: postgresql, roles, creation

As PostgreSQL doesn't dump object creation date so I want to manually dump user creation date by using trigger and functions. I have created trigger and functions but it's not working.

```
CREATE TABLE user_audits (
   usesysid INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   usename varchar NOT NULL,
   created_on TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
);

============================
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_creation()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.usename <> OLD.usename THEN
         INSERT INTO user_audits(usesysid,usename,created_on)
         VALUES(usesysid,usename,now());
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
=================================
CREATE TRIGGER user_creation
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_creation();
```

This is important for audit purpose, for now I am using log file to check creation date but it will rotate after sometime.
Please suggest the better way to dump user creation date in table so that I can retrieve the information anytime.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar excercise with the following tables:

1. The `user_tbl` table having only a identity column `usersysid` and the `username`

```
CREATE TABLE user_tbl (
   usersysid INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   username varchar NOT NULL
);
```

2. The `user_audits` table, slightly modified version of yours: where i added an `id` identity field. I removed the identity from the `usersysid` field (since it'll be populated with the one coming from `user_tbl`)

```
CREATE TABLE user_audits (
   id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   usersysid INT,
   username varchar NOT NULL,
   created_on TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
);
```

Now the function, I check if the `OLD.username` is null, this means that is an insert, if `NEW.username <> OLD.username` then is an update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_creation()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.username is null OR NEW.username <> OLD.username THEN
         INSERT INTO user_audits(usersysid,username,created_on)
         VALUES(NEW.usersysid,NEW.username,now());
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
;
```

And finally the trigger, which is fired both on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_creation
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON user_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE user_creation();
```

Now if I create two new rows and update one with the following

```
insert into user_tbl (username) values('Carlo');
insert into user_tbl (username) values('Gianni');
update user_tbl set username='Giorgio' where usersysid=1;
```

I end up with the `user_tbl` containing the 2 expected rows

```
defaultdb=> select * from user_tbl;
 usersysid | username 
-----------+----------
         2 | Gianni
         1 | Giorgio
(2 rows)
```

and the `user_audits` tables containing 3 rows (2 for the insert + 1 for the update)

```
defaultdb=> select * from user_audits;
 id | usersysid | username |         created_on         
----+-----------+----------+----------------------------
  1 |         1 | Carlo    | 2021-06-04 13:57:44.810889
  2 |         2 | Gianni   | 2021-06-04 13:58:14.680878
  3 |         1 | Giorgio  | 2021-06-04 13:58:44.702364
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Ftisiot, it's working on new table creation but I want to implement on default pg user table. Everything configured  except the trigger, it's says pg_user or user is a view;

Comment: exact error:ERROR:  "pg_user" is a view
DETAIL:  Views cannot have row-level BEFORE or AFTER triggers.
SQL state: 42809